# node.js не устанавливает соединение с базой данных

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin, node-modules

При попытке создать соединение с базой данных хранящейся на локалхосте ничего не происходит.В консоле не появляется никаких сообщений, программа просто висит.
ps(все модули устновил правльно, все порты названия и тому подобное тоже правльно указал)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112936/discussion-on-question-by---node-js-----).

Answer (score 0):

После не продолжительной беседы. Ошибка была найдена в номере порта сервера баз данных. Был указан порт номер 8888 когда сам сервер был настроен на порт 8889.